# returning several errors through one variable?

Tags: php

For my registration form I've got a function that checks if all the fields are correct.

If the fields are not correct a variable `$errors` is passed through the session with `$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;` and the user is sent back to the registration page where an error message is displayed.

What I would like to do is being able to display an error message next to each incorrect inputs, so if for example a user didn't enter both his username / password and got the captcha wrong, something like this would be displayed :

> [ input for username ] **please enter your username**
>
> [ input for password ] **a password is required**
>
> [ input for e-mail ]
>
> [ input for captcha ] **try again**

I know I could create this by setting a different variable for each error, and passing them all through the session, and then check if each of them is set, but that wouldn't look very clean.

How do I achieve this ? using `$errors` as an array so I can stock an error for each incorrect inputs ? (I haven't learned to use them yet but I will if that's the way to do this).

Here is my code for more clarity :

```
            if (!isset($username) || $username == ''){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (!ctype_alnum($username)){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (gg::getUser($username)){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (gg::getUser($email, 'email')){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (!isset($password) || $password == ''){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (!isset($passwordconf)){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (!isset($_POST['captcha'])){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if ($password != $passwordconf){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }

            if ((int)$captcha != (int)$_SESSION['captcha_answer']){
                    $errors = "";
                    gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
                }


if ($error != false) {
            $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
            header('Location: ' .ggconf::get('base_url'). '/user/register.php');

        }
```

Comment: use an array for the errors, and align the names of the fields with the array index, so when you're redrawing the form, you know what index in the array to check, to see if it was submitted incorrectly. e.g. if your username field is called `username`, set `$_SESSION['errors']['username']` to be true, then when you're redrawing the form, if `$_SESSION['errors']['username']` is true, show that error message. or use client-side validation :) or use html5 form field validation :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I am not willing html5 field validation since it doesn't really allow any forms of customizations of the errors messages (and I also need php to check existing username/emails). Does `$_SESSION['errors']['username']` allow me tu return an error for differents inputs ? for example if the severals fields are incorrect. I'll look into that anyways, thanks!

Comment: Use client-side JS for an initial sanity-check (user-convenience) and then - on the server - perform another verification. Post errors back to the client from both.

Comment: Also is there a way to check if a specific parameter is defined and its value ? For instance if the username already exists it would add a parameter to $errors named "username" with the value "already_exist", and another parameter would be added if for exemple the password is missing. I would then echo the error message depending if the parameter is set and its value. Would that work ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, yes I'm planning on doing that at least for the email field and to check if the password confirmation matches the first password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a session array and use it to validate the input errors in the form submission.

```
$errors = //array
if (!isset($username) || $username == ''){
        $errors['username']= "username error";
        gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
    }

  if (gg::getUser($email, 'email')){
        $errors['email']= "email error";
        gg::writeLog('registration failed - error');
    }
    ......
```

Now in your form you could so something like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($errors['username'])){
  echo $errors['username'];
}?>
//html for username input 

$errors= array(
    "username" => "bar",
    "email" => "foo",
);
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to look into this right now, also check my second comment on the main post, your answer seems to fit what I had in mind.

Comment: Also, when I pass the variable through the session, do I have to repeat `$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors['username'];` for each parameter or is using `$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;` going to send the variable with all the parameters already defined ?

Comment: Another question, can you explain your first line `$errors = //array` to define the variable ? I'm not sure to understand how arrays work

Comment: for first question, as long as you assign the array to session variable you`ll be fine, for second you can define an associative array, see my updated answer

Comment: It's still very blurry so I'll follow your link and learn a bit more about arrays, I'll update later, thanks !

Comment: Allright ! Everything is working, and even more. Thanks a lot for your help !